# Can I use "Bei + clause?"

Tags: meaning, translation

Kann man Folgendes sagen?

> Bei meinen Fehler zu zeigen hilfst du mir sehr. Damit kann ich meine Sprachkenntnisse verbessern.

Comment: Why do you think "bei" fits? "Bei" is wrong but there are many correct options. What do you want to express? "Mir meine Fehler zu zeigen, hilft mir sehr", "Indem du mir meine Fehler zeigst, hilfst du mir sehr." Dadurch dass, du mir meine Fehler...."

Comment: @Iris I think in English it was "By showing me my error you help me a lot". "By" and "Bei" sound the same, that's why they often get confused.

Comment: There are hundreds of words that sound similar. In rare cases they are always a good translation, sometimes they are just sometimes a good translation, but most times they are just nonsense. ;)

Comment: @PerlDuck, oh right.... and even google translate gives a correct translation: https://translate.google.de/?biw=1525&bih=733&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.135974163,d.bGs&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=de&client=tw-ob#en/de/By%20showing%20me%20my%20error

Comment: *by* and *bei* are so called "false friends". A common mistake for German students is to translate *Ich aß Kuchen bei meiner Oma* to *I ate cake by my grandma*. While the translation does make sense, it is not a proper translation of the German original sentence. Things get even worse with other false friends like *become/bekommen*.

Answer (score 3):

Nein, das sollte man nicht sagen.

*Bei* ist in diesem Kontext definitv falsch. Das Deutsche *bei* und das Englische *by* stehen nur sehr selten in einem Zusammenhang, auch wenn es sich ähnlich anhört.

Folgende Beispiele zeigen, wie man es richtig macht:

> **Indem** du mir meine Fehler aufzeigst, hilfst du mir sehr.

Oder:

> Du hilfst mir sehr, **indem** du mir meine Fehler aufzeigst.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. You never use the German "bei" in the way it can be used in the English language to show a cause.

> By teaching me those fundamental concepts, you helped me a lot.

will always translate to something like what Clijsters said, using conjunctions like "indem", "dadurch, dass" and you then have 2 sentences. But it will never translate to "bei".

> Du hast mir sehr geholfen, indem du mir diese fundamentalen Konzepte beigebracht hast.
>
> Du hast mir sehr geholfen dadurch, dass du mir diese fundamentalen Konzepte beigebracht hast.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Just one comment, why did you change the example?

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the other answers, I'd say that even though the English *by* can not be generally translated to *bei*, you **can** use *bei* to construct sentences that express what you mean - just not the way you did it.

So, the short answer is: No, your sentence is not correct. Possible sentences with *bei* that do work would be:

> Beim Aufzeigen meiner Fehler hilfst du mir sehr.
> Beim Auffinden meiner Fehler hilfst du mir sehr.

Retranslating this back to English shows the difference:

> Beim Aufzeigen meiner Fehler hilfst du mir sehr.
> You are a great help with showing me my mistakes.
>
> Beim Auffinden meiner Fehler hilfst du mir sehr.
> You are a great help with finding my mistakes.

As you can see, the *bei* in German has a different connotation as the *by* in English. The *by* tells us what someone else does to help you (=> finding miskates). The German *bei* indicates that you are already doing something, that someone else helps you with (=> he helps you with finding mistakes).

So generally, *by* translates to *durch* or *indem*.